# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value C#

Tags: asp.net

Below is the code where I compute date by subtracting TimeSpan from Today's Date.

```
DateTime todayDate = DateTime.Today;
TimeSpan minTS = new TimeSpan(6570, 0, 0, 0, 0);
TimeSpan maxTS = new TimeSpan(7300, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime minDate = todayDate.Subtract(minTS);
DateTime maxDate = todayDate.Subtract(maxTS);
```

My Query is as below:

```
sql = "select AId,AName,DOB,Religion from Applicant,Creator as C where (C.CId = Applicant.CId and Approved = 'Approved' and Gender !='" + gend + "' and AId !=" + id + ") and (Applicant.Status = '" + status.Items[status.SelectedIndex].ToString() + "' and Applicant.DOB BETWEEN '" + maxDate + "' and '" + minDate + "')";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);      // use your existing SqlCommand here (don't use select *)
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();                       // create a DataSet object to hold you table(s)... this can contain more than 1 table
                    da.Fill(ds, "Comment");
```

This works fine for me. But when I change the values of TimeSpan to

```
TimeSpan(7300, 0, 0, 0, 0);
TimeSpan maxTS = new TimeSpan(9125, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I get the following error:
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
I hope there is no problem with the query, because the same query works fine for TimeSpan(6570,0,0,0,0) and TimeSpan(7300,0,0,0,0). It gives error when i change it to TimeSpan(7300,0,0,0,0) and TimeSpan(9125,0,0,0,0)

I am not getting where I am going wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert error: the conversion of a varchar datatype to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073662/insert-error-the-conversion-of-a-varchar-datatype-to-a-datetime-data-type-resul) ... among many others.

Comment: What is your DOB data type in DB?

Comment: it is datetime. It is working fine with TimeSpan(6570,0,0,0,) but when I change it to TimeSpan(7300,0,0,0) I get the error

Comment: @SelvaTS DOB data type in DB is DateTime only. Please help me out.

Comment: I found solution for the above problem. I just changed the query as below:

Comment: `sql = "select AId,AName,DOB,Religion from Applicant,Creator as C where (C.CId = Applicant.CId and Approved = 'Approved' and Gender !='" + gend + "' and AId !=" + id + ") and (Applicant.Status = '" + status.Items[status.SelectedIndex].ToString() + "' and Applicant.DOB BETWEEN @maxDate and @minDate)";
cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@minDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = minDate;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maxDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = maxDate;`